# XPath 1.0 fetch the child record

Tags: xpath

Below is the XML

```
<on-error-continue type="APIKIT:BAD_REQUEST" enableNotifications="true" logException="true">
 <set-variable value="200" doc:name="httpStatus" variableName="httpStatus" />
 <set-variable value="Bad request" doc:name="logDescription" variableName="logDescription" />
 <flow-ref doc:name="global-prepare-error-response-sub-flow" name="global-prepare-error-response-sub-flow"/>
</on-error-continue>
<on-error-continue type="APIKIT:TOO_MANY_REQUEST" enableNotifications="true" logException="true">
 <set-variable value="200" doc:name="httpStatus" variableName="httpStatus" />
 <set-variable value="Many request" doc:name="logDescription" variableName="logDescription" />
 <flow-ref doc:name="global-prepare-error-response-sub-flow" name="global-prepare-error-response-sub-flow"/>
</on-error-continue>
```

Wanted to get the single record

> "set-variable value="200" doc:name="httpStatus" variableName="httpStatus"

using xPath 1.0 expression: Parent is -->on-error-continue type="APIKIT:BAD_REQUEST" and child is -->set-variable value = "200".

Have tried below expression. It is working fine with Xpath2.0 but not working with 1.0

```
//*[local-name()='on-error-continue'][@*[local-name()='type' and .='APIKIT:BAD_REQUEST']]/set-variable[@value='200' and @variableName='httpStatus']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this [handy website](https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester), I took the xml and put it in a root element, `<root>YOUR XML</root>`.

With this XPath:

```
//root/on-error-continue[@type='APIKIT:TOO_MANY_REQUEST']/set-variable[@value='200' and @variableName='httpStatus']
```

I was able to extract the matching record. Try it yourself and replace the `root` with `*` in the above XPath. You should see the records that you're seeking.

The wildcard operator can be used like any element in the path.

Comment: Cheers! I modified accordingly and got the expected result. Here is my final version for getting the result //*[local-name()='on-error-continue'][@type='APIKIT:TOO_MANY_REQUEST']/*[local-name()='set-variable'][@variableName='httpStatus' and @value!='200']